# how can i add admins to a private github repository, there is no manage access option?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I have a github(enterprise) repository(private repo) and want to make a someone the admin of the same. The issue here is that i don't see from where i can do that there's only an option to add collaborators and no manage access option.
can someone tell how this can be done?

Comment: github and gitlab are different products from different companies - please make clear what you are asking about and remove the other tag.

Comment: @phry corrected

Answer (score -1):

1. Open your repository's **Settings**
2. Click **Collaborators & teams** in the sidebar
3. Add your coworker as a collaborator (if you haven't already)
4. Select your coworker's **Role** and change it to **Admin**

For more information, see [Managing teams and people with access to your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/managing-teams-and-people-with-access-to-your-repository)

Comment: this is not possible for private repository

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: if you go into a private GitHub reopsitory on "Settings" there is no "Collaborators & Teams", there is only "Collaborators" and you can't set the "Role". You can only add them to the repository but there are no roles in the private repository like "Admin, "Write" etc.

Comment: I haven't used Enterprise in a while. Have you tried moving it to an organization or team?

Comment: nope, I am considering a private repository in a profile